# Linux kernel module freezing the computer while iterating over running processes to access process opened files

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel

I am developing a kernel module using kernel version 3.x.

I have a function that is responsible to determine if a running process has a given file opened.

Here is my code (see my comments after):

```
struct task_struct *    process = NULL;
struct files_struct *   task_files = NULL;
struct fdtable *        fdt = NULL;
int                     fd_i;
char                    tmpbuf[256];
char *                  process_path = "";

for_each_process(process)
{
    // Ignore processes without files
    if (process->files == NULL)
        continue;

    printk(KERN_INFO "task_lock()...\n");
    task_lock(process);
    printk(KERN_INFO "task_lock() DONE\n");
    task_files = process->files;
    printk(KERN_INFO "task_unlock()...\n");
    task_unlock(process);
    printk(KERN_INFO "task_unlock() DONE\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "files_fdtable()...\n");
    fdt = files_fdtable(task_files);
    printk(KERN_INFO "files_fdtable() DONE\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "Iterating files...\n");
    for (fd_i = 0; fd_i < fdt->max_fds; fd_i++)
    {
        if (fcheck_files(task_files, fd_i) == my_file)
        {
            if (process->mm)
            {
                if (process->mm->exe_file)
                {

                    process_path = d_path(&process->mm->exe_file->f_path, tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf));
                    break;
                } else {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "process->mm->exe_file is NULL\n");
                }
            } else {
                printk(KERN_INFO "process->mm is NULL\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Files iteration finished\n");
}
```

This code is working and the variable `process_path` contains the path of the process where the given file is opened.
But when there is huge load on the machine (so going through this code really often), the machine freeze (after a certain amount of time) and the latest printed debug is:

```
task_unlock() DONE
```

Then I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

- [for_each_process](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.2#L2284) isn't calling [spin_lock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L283) and [spin_unlock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L323) on processes so I'm using [task_lock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.2#L2350) and [task_unlock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.2#L2355).
- [files_fdtable](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fdtable.h?v=3.2#L67) is calling [spin_lock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L283) and [spin_unlock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L323) so I don't.
- [fcheck_files](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fdtable.h?v=3.2#L83) is also calling [spin_lock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L283) and [spin_unlock](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=3.2#L323) so I don't.
- [d_path](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c?v=3.2#L2600) is taking care to lock so I don't do it.

Could you please explain me why my code is freezing the machine and how to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe consult the kernel mailing list? SO is too broad a site for specific questions like this.

Comment: Try protecting your code with rcu_read_lock() / rcu_read_unlock(), otherwise processes may disappear from list while you are iterating.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `task_lock()`?  The `task_files = process->files;` line needs a *lock*?  I think you may need it while iterating or something else.  Is the `fdt` structure going to be consistent across your run?  What if a task reschedules and `closes`/`opens` a file while you traverse?  Also the last thing to `printk`, does mean the crash happens there.  It could be after words and some other `printk` didn't flush.

Comment: @Inspired thanks but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Just a quick comment for you @artlessnoise: I miss knowledge but I did it based on the code of method [get_files_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c?v=3.2#L490).

Comment: Notice that `atomic_inc()` is done in the `task_lock()` and `task_unlock()`.  You can not cut and paste kernel code as easily as regular code.  Every code sequence has meaning that is often quite asynchronous.  It is easy to create code full of race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The way you designed your module is responsible for system being freeze. Note that, you've used for_each_process(), that means, it'll traverse every process of the system. So, when you put load on the system the number of process gets bigger. Moreover, inside your for_each_process() loop you're calling task_lock/unlock() and tried various operations on processes, all these operations are expensive, cause they all have their own lock to take. When system load is low they're not noticeable, but the complexity of your modules runtime increases as system gets more and more loaded, but remains less noticeable on low load. I'd suggest to use feature like ftrace to instrument your module also avoid over use of printk (cause printk also needs to be scheduled, klogd is used on that purpose). And with low load inspect how your module runs inside kernel. Measure how much time it spends on every loop, you get to know yourself. Kernel is a big beast, a lot of things happens inside...

Comment: Thanks for ftrace, it would help me it's sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
read_lock(&tasklist_lock);

do_each_thread(g, p) {
  task_lock(p);

  if (check_for_file(p, file)) {
    task_unlock(p);
    goto next;
  }

  task_unlock(p);
} while_each_thread(g, p);

next:

read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
```

Comment: While I was looking for each method definition I wasn't able to find the definition of the method `check_for_file`. Could you please tell me where it is defined ?

Comment: That's the function `that is responsible to determine if a running process has a given file opened.`

Comment: I was asking where the function is declared as I can't find it in the kernel sources. Sorry if my previous comment wasn't clear...

Comment: Also while I compile this code I got the error "WARNING: "tasklist_lock" [/home/zedtux/Developments/Douane/lkm/douane.ko] undefined!"

Answer (score -1):

I have finally fixed my code.

I have first implemented a kind of caching of the relation between a process and an opened file in a linked list, and re-factored my code in multiples methods (and after having fixed memory leaks) it is now working.

Thank you all for your help.